# Расположение строк матрицы по возрастанию

Tags: c++

Вечер добрый. По какой-то непонятной мне причине этот код вообще ничего не изменяет в матрице. Задача: расположить строки заданной матрицы по возрастанию количества одинаковых элементов в каждой строке. Вот код:

```
int main()
{
    const int N = 5;
    int m[N][N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            cin >> m[i][j];

    int s[N], n[N][N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            for (int k = j + 1; k < N; k++)
                if (m[i][j] == m[i][k])
                    n[i][j]++;
        int maxCount = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            if (n[i][j] > maxCount)
                maxCount = n[i][j];
        s[i] = maxCount + 1;
        cout << s[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << "nn";

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int maxCount = s[i];
        int index = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
            if (s[j] > maxCount) {
                maxCount = s[j];
                index = j;
            }

        int temp = s[i];
        s[i] = maxCount;
        s[index] = temp;

        for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
            temp = m[i][k];
            m[i][k] = m[index][k];
            m[index][k] = temp;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            cout << m[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @RubyNub: 1 1 1 1 1 значит, что все элементы в строках различны, количество одинаковых элементов всегда 1, и что и вправду нечего менять? Попробуйте ввести другие элементы в матрицу.

Comment: @RubyNub: Помогло?

Comment: @VladD, да, благодарю

Comment: @RubyNub: отлично, тогда я сделаю из этого ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы забыли первоначальное заполнение массива `n` нулями.

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        n[i][j] = 0;
```

Иначе там могут быть случайные значения.

Comment: Уже избавился от этой доп матрицы - понял что можно считать используя один массив) Спасибо еще раз.

Comment: @RubyNub: пожалуйста! :) да, и правда, она была не нужна. проходите скорее эту нудятину и переходите к реально интересным задачам.